# How to pass a variable to callback of setState in React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following event handler. And the problem is `e` is not available in callback function. How can I fix this?

```
handleChange(e){
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      ...prevState,
      university: {
        ...prevState.university,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value // error line
      }
    }));
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
handleChange({ target: { name, value } }){
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      ...prevState,
      university: {
        ...prevState.university,
        [name]: value
      }
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `name` property in event.target. 
`Create a "value" state and initialize with event.target.value`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Check the edited version.